# how to count continuous numbers of events in a long time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  a data frame with columns: year, month, day, and prec as header. How can I count the longest number of day having the value 0  in 'prec' column for each month.

```
datasub = data[data['prec'] ==0.0]

datasub.groupby(['year','month'])['prec'].count()
```

from this code I did not got the value result which I expected

and the data looks like below:

```html
Out[70]: 
      year  month  day  prec
0     1981      1    1   1.5
1     1981      1    2   0.0
2     1981      1    3   0.0
3     1981      1    4   0.4
4     1981      1    5   0.0
5     1981      1    6   1.0
6     1981      1    7   1.9
7     1981      1    8   0.6
8     1981      1    9   3.7
9     1981      1   10   0.0
10    1981      1   11   0.0
11    1981      1   12   0.0
12    1981      1   13   0.0
13    1981      1   14  12.2
14    1981      1   15   1.7
15    1981      1   16   0.6
16    1981      1   17   0.9
17    1981      1   18   0.6
18    1981      1   19   0.4
19    1981      1   20   0.2
20    1981      1   21   1.4
21    1981      1   22   3.2
22    1981      1   23   0.0
23    1981      1   24   0.2
24    1981      1   25   1.2
25    1981      1   26   0.0
26    1981      1   27   0.0
27    1981      1   28   0.0
28    1981      1   29   0.0
29    1981      1   30   0.2
...    ...    ...  ...   ...
3987  1991     12    2   0.0
3988  1991     12    3   0.0
3989  1991     12    4   0.0
3990  1991     12    5   0.5
3991  1991     12    6   0.4
3992  1991     12    7   1.2
3993  1991     12    8   0.0
3994  1991     12    9   0.0
3995  1991     12   10   0.0
3996  1991     12   11   0.0
3997  1991     12   12   0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate some artificial data
# ============================================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4000), columns=['prec'], index=pd.date_range('1981-01-01', periods=4000, freq='D'))
df['prec'] = np.where(df['prec'] > 0, df['prec'], 0.0)
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['day'] = df.index.day
df

              prec  year  month  day
1981-01-01  1.7641  1981      1    1
1981-01-02  0.4002  1981      1    2
1981-01-03  0.9787  1981      1    3
1981-01-04  2.2409  1981      1    4
1981-01-05  1.8676  1981      1    5
1981-01-06  0.0000  1981      1    6
1981-01-07  0.9501  1981      1    7
1981-01-08  0.0000  1981      1    8
1981-01-09  0.0000  1981      1    9
1981-01-10  0.4106  1981      1   10
1981-01-11  0.1440  1981      1   11
1981-01-12  1.4543  1981      1   12
1981-01-13  0.7610  1981      1   13
1981-01-14  0.1217  1981      1   14
1981-01-15  0.4439  1981      1   15
...            ...   ...    ...  ...
1991-11-30  0.9764  1991     11   30
1991-12-01  0.1772  1991     12    1
1991-12-02  0.0000  1991     12    2
1991-12-03  0.1067  1991     12    3
1991-12-04  0.0000  1991     12    4
1991-12-05  0.0000  1991     12    5
1991-12-06  0.5765  1991     12    6
1991-12-07  0.0653  1991     12    7
1991-12-08  0.0000  1991     12    8
1991-12-09  0.3949  1991     12    9
1991-12-10  0.0000  1991     12   10
1991-12-11  1.7796  1991     12   11
1991-12-12  0.0000  1991     12   12
1991-12-13  1.5771  1991     12   13
1991-12-14  0.0000  1991     12   14

[4000 rows x 4 columns]

# processing
# ===========================================
def func(group):
    return (group.prec != 0).astype(int).cumsum().value_counts().values[0] - 1

df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(func)

year  month
1981  1        2
      2        5
      3        4
      4        2
      5        3
      6        4
      7        3
      8        5
      9        5
      10       2
      11       6
      12       6
1982  1        5
      2        3
      3        4
              ..
1990  10       9
      11       4
      12       5
1991  1        6
      2        4
      3        4
      4        4
      5        4
      6        9
      7        3
      8        5
      9        6
      10       6
      11       3
      12       2
dtype: int64
```

The idea here is to use a impulse for non-zero values and then create a step function.

```
# take a look at a sample group
# ===========================================
group = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).get_group((1981,1))
group
# create a step function
group['step_func'] = (group.prec != 0).astype(int).cumsum()

              prec  year  month  day  step_func
1981-01-01  1.7641  1981      1    1          1
1981-01-02  0.4002  1981      1    2          2
1981-01-03  0.9787  1981      1    3          3
1981-01-04  2.2409  1981      1    4          4
1981-01-05  1.8676  1981      1    5          5
1981-01-06  0.0000  1981      1    6          5
1981-01-07  0.9501  1981      1    7          6
1981-01-08  0.0000  1981      1    8          6
1981-01-09  0.0000  1981      1    9          6
1981-01-10  0.4106  1981      1   10          7
1981-01-11  0.1440  1981      1   11          8
1981-01-12  1.4543  1981      1   12          9
1981-01-13  0.7610  1981      1   13         10
1981-01-14  0.1217  1981      1   14         11
1981-01-15  0.4439  1981      1   15         12
1981-01-16  0.3337  1981      1   16         13
1981-01-17  1.4941  1981      1   17         14
1981-01-18  0.0000  1981      1   18         14
1981-01-19  0.3131  1981      1   19         15
1981-01-20  0.0000  1981      1   20         15
1981-01-21  0.0000  1981      1   21         15
1981-01-22  0.6536  1981      1   22         16
1981-01-23  0.8644  1981      1   23         17
1981-01-24  0.0000  1981      1   24         17
1981-01-25  2.2698  1981      1   25         18
1981-01-26  0.0000  1981      1   26         18
1981-01-27  0.0458  1981      1   27         19
1981-01-28  0.0000  1981      1   28         19
1981-01-29  1.5328  1981      1   29         20
1981-01-30  1.4694  1981      1   30         21
1981-01-31  0.1549  1981      1   31         22

# value_counts, pick the max value and subtract 1
group['step_func'].value_counts().values[0] - 1

2
```

### Update:

using `.values[0]` causes confusions for integer index. Replace it by `.iloc[0]`.

```
# processing
# ===========================================
def func(group):
    return (group.prec != 0).astype(int).cumsum()[group.prec == 0].value_counts().iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Jianxun Li now it woks :)

Comment: and also how to find out the year month having this max value i.e having maximum number of zero

Comment: could you please give me an idea on how to calculate for non-zero value i tried    def func(group): return (group.prec<=0).astype(int).cumsum().value_counts().values[0] - 1 but not working